# Find element by property value

Tags: javascript, selenium, dom, selenium-webdriver, nightwatch.js

I'm testing a web application using [Nightwatch.js](http://nightwatchjs.org/), which uses [Selenium WebDriver](http://www.seleniumhq.org/projects/webdriver/) to interact with the browser. In my app I have a dynamically created list of items differentiated only by their names and the names are displayed as `<input>` values. I need to find an item by its name.

Example HTML representation of document structure:

```
<div class="item">
  <input>  <!-- current value: "first" -->
</div>
<div class="item">
  <input>  <!-- current value: "second" -->
</div>
<div class="item">
  <input>  <!-- current value: "first" -->
</div>
```

I need to find `div.item` containing an input with the value `second`.

Note that the value of an `<input>` is determined by the value of its `value` *property*, which might be different from the value of its `value` *attribute*. In my case, the DOM is manipulated by [React](https://facebook.github.io/react/), so the inputs might not have the `value` attribute at all.

**Is there a way to find element by *property* value with Nightwatch (or Selenium WebDriver API)?**

I looked over the WebDriver [documentation](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp#locating-ui-elements-webelements) and the only way I see is [executing](http://nightwatchjs.org/api/execute.html) custom JavaScript code, which has some serious drawbacks (e.g. requires own implementation of waiting for element to appear and doesn't interact with Nightwatch page objects). As far as I can see, all of the other methods are concerned with looking at the HTML only (so *attributes* at best, not *properties*).

---

*Just to be completely clear, using selectors like `input[value=...]` (CSS) or `//input[@value=...]` (XPath) is **not** a solution, as it performs lookup by attribute value, not property value.*

Comment: FYI, not `nightwatch.js` specific, but a `protractor`-specific solution could be to use the newly introduced [`by.js` locator](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.By.js).

Comment: @alecxe That's interesting info, but it seems to have the same usability as  Nightwatch/WebDriver [execute](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/JsonWireProtocol#sessionsessionidexecute). (Note the two-way translation of WebElements to/from DOMElements in arguments and return value.)

Comment: Yeah, I'm afraid there is no other way except going down to executing custom JS.

Comment: can you provide an example site ? Then i can test on it.

Comment: @BaoTran Sorry, my use-case is a proprietary app. The problem itself is quite simple to simulate though.

Comment: What about using the xpath like _//div/input[contains(text(), "second")]_ ?

Comment: @Michael Please note the difference between _attributes_ and _properties_. See the underline note in the description.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.elements()` to get a list of elements with `class="item"` and then iterate through all elements using `.getValue()` to get the value property of each input. If it matches the name you want, return the element.

```
function getElementsByValue(xpathSelector, expectedValue, callback) {
  const foundElements = [];
  browser.elements('xpath', xpathSelector, ({ value }) => value.forEach(inputEl => {
    browser.elementIdValue(inputEl.ELEMENT, result => {
      if (result.value === expectedValue) {
        foundElements.push(inputEl);
      }
    });
  });
  browser.perform(() => callback(foundElements));
}
```

Comment: Nice, you get a point. My question is too generic to accept it as an answer though, as it only works for `value`. I'll clean it up a bit at least.

Comment: Thank you for the improvement :)